# Video can be streamed on Chrome but not on other players

Tags: c++, qt, http, networking, http-headers

in my current project C++/Qt, I am trying to make a file server to stream videos. I can stream a video from the app to Chrome, but I can't stream it to other players (example - VLC). I have tried other libraries and they work, but mine doesn't work. 
I guess it's a problem with the headers. Here are the headers -

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Length: VIDEO-SIZE\r\n
Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n\r\n
```

I also have support for partial video support (to use the seeking functionality), and here are it's headers -

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n
Content-Length: VIDEO-SIZE\r\n
Content-Type: video/mp4\r\n
Content-Range: bytes RANGE/VIDEO-SIZE\r\n\r\n
```

I  am developing the app in C++ with Qt Network libraries, and the code is very simple. Basically what it does is sends the above headers, and then the video. The CPP code is below (Not exactly a good code, just a basic draft)

```
QTcpSocket *clientConnection = server->nextPendingConnection();
connect(clientConnection, SIGNAL(disconnected()),
    clientConnection, SLOT(deleteLater()));
clientConnection->waitForReadyRead();

QMap<QString, QString> requestMap;
while (!clientConnection->atEnd()) {
    QString line(clientConnection->readLine());
    qDebug()<<line;
    if (line.indexOf(":") <= 0 || line.isEmpty())
        continue;
   line.replace("\r\n", "");
   QString key(line.left(line.indexOf(":"))),
            value(line.mid(line.indexOf(":") + 2, line.length()));
   requestMap.insert(key, value);
   qDebug() << "KEY: " << key << " VALUE: " << value << "\n";
}
img->open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QByteArray block;
QDataStream out(&block, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_8);
QString header, imgsize(QString::number(img->size()));
if(requestMap.contains("Range")){
    QString range = requestMap["Range"];
    range = range.mid(6, range.length()); // 'bytes=' is 6 chars
    qint64 seek = range.left(range.indexOf("-")).toInt();
    if (range.endsWith("-"))
        range.append(QString::number(img->size() - 1));
    header = "HTTP/1.0 206 PARTIAL CONTENT\r\n"
             "Content-Length: "+imgsize+"\r\n"
             "Content-Range: bytes "+range+"/"+imgsize + "\r\n"
             "Content-Type: "+db.mimeTypeForFile(fileinfo).name()+"\r\n\r\n";
            img->seek(seek);
} else header = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
                "Content-Length: "+imgsize+"\r\n"
                "Content-Type: "+db.mimeTypeForFile(fileinfo).name()+"\r\n\r\n";
out << header.toLatin1();
clientConnection->write(block);
clientConnection->waitForBytesWritten();
block.resize(65536);

while(!img->atEnd())
{
    qint64 read = img->read(block.data(), 65536);
    clientConnection->write(block, read);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `QDataStream` in your code. Just create `QByteArray`, append your header, and send it via `clientConnection->write()`